# Convert JavaScript Regex to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

How can I convert the following Regex statement into C#?

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line.Trim(), @"/^[A-Za-z-.]+([,;]\s?[A-Za-z-.]+)*$/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
    //do something
```

The pattern mentioned in the Match method is the one I picked from my javascript method.
It basically matches names such as `Jane,Doe` `Jane;Doe` `Jane, Doe; Jack, Doe`

Please advice.

Comment: Please clarify: how is the code you currently have not doing what you want it to?

Comment: I rolled this back to the revision one, because if you edit the question to include the solution from the answer, it then becomes useless.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Remove `/` at the start and the end of the string.

Comment: Also, the `a-z`s can be removed (or the `IgnoreCase` option), and the dash should be at the end of the character class `[A-Z.-]`.

Comment: It does work for me here http://regexhero.net/tester/ which uses .NET Regex engine, for all of your examples. What string does it fail on?

Comment: I found my error. Was a spelling mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SoulSlayer Why was the question edited to include this answer? It's confusing when I look at this and see that the answer was already implemented in the question.