# JavaScript RegEx to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation, backend

I have a regular expression for validating e-mail addresses in JavaScript:

> ^(([\w]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$

I need to convert it to C# format.
What are the changes needed on the above JS Regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989081/email-model-validation-with-dataannotations-and-datatype

Comment: you can use [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] for validating

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536061/convert-javascript-regex-to-c-sharp

Comment: Sameer Ahmed:No need to use data Annotations.Need the Exact Regex in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@"^[\w!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*" + "@" + @"((([-\w]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3})]|(([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$"

Got this regex perfectly suits my requirements.
Which allows IP addresses with or without [] enclosed